# Redefine typedef within local scope

Tags: c++, scope, typedef

I need to customize a typedef statement depending on a boolean value a. How can I solve this?

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename my_type>
ClassA{...};

int main ()
{
    bool a = false;

    typedef int my_type;
    if (a == true)
    {
        typedef int my_type;
    }
    else
    {
        typedef double my_type;
    }

    typedef ClassA<my_type> my_type2;

}
```

Comment: you can use templates instead of typedef?

Comment: Unfortunately it would be only a very minor change in a huge code project, so I'm forced to use typedef...

Comment: Currently, your typedef goes out of scope the moment you create `my_type b`

Comment: This sounds like it could be solved using a "union" instead of a typedef.

Comment: A type is a compile time entity, and can't depend on a run time one.

Comment: Note that even if you change the definition of `my_type`, the result of `1 / 3` will remain an `int`. You might want to use `my_type(1) / my_type(3)`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Already addressed that in the answer section, the correct place for such information!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: As that wasn't asked about, it seems reasonable to comment. Also, when I added the comment, your answer didn't, yet (or just barely) included the fix. It still doesn't point out the problem.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: It does.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You do mention that there _is_ a problem. There is no indication of _what_ the problem is, though.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: The problem is that types are a compile-time notion and cannot depend on run-time factors. The requirement is impossible to satisfy. It's as simple as that. C++ has no support for this requirement.

Comment: Actually I need "my_type" also in the rest of the main function (I've changed the code)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: yes. I do understand the concept of types in C++ at they happen at compile time. I also realize that my comment did not address solving the problem asked for. My comment merely pointed out that changing only the type of the result won't cut it and why that is the case.

Comment: @user1403546: as LigtnessRacesinOrbit already pointed out: _that_ won't work at all. You'll need to factor your code somehow into a different entity, e.g., a function template.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: you can't. Types are a compile-time notion and cannot depend on run-time factors.

However, function calls *can*! So, move your logic into a function template and call it conditionally:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void foo()
{
   const T b = T(1) / T(3);
   std::cout << "b = " << b << std::endl;
}

int main ()
{
    bool a = false;

    if (a == true)
       foo<int>();
    else
       foo<double>();
}
```

This could, of course, be finessed, possibly with a `boost::variant` and some visitors.

I have at least fixed your problem with integer division. Ish.

Comment: Actually I need "my_type" also in the rest of the main function (I've changed the code)

Comment: @user1403546: (a) Don't change the code after I've already written an answer 30 minutes ago. (b) Tough. (c) Do as I suggested. Put "the rest of the main function" into the function template.